# Background de ImageButtons

Tags: java, android, android-resources

Eu tenho um `ImageButton` e quando clico nele queria que o `Background` dele passasse para outro `ImageButton`.

Tenho `View v` do primeiro `ImageButton`, e `imgB6` é o `ImageButton` que quero receba o background de v, e dá erro em `v.getBackground()`:

`findViewById(R.id.imgB6).setBackgroundResource(v.getBackground());`

`v.getBackground()` ta a dar erro não sei pq, uma vez que é um drawable.

`v` é recebido por parâmetro quando no método `Onclick`, e tem um `drawable` correspondente!

Queria passar o `Backgound` de `v(View)` para `imgB6(ImageButton)`.

Comment: Tem algum código? Coloque o erro na sua pergunta.

Comment: Coloque o xml dos dois imageView

Comment: sao `ImageButtons`, um vem por parâmetro a `View` que chamo `v`, e desta `View` quero pegar no `background` e por em outro `ImageButton imgB6`. Entao `findViewById(R.id.imgB6).setBackgroundResource(v.getBackground());`

Comment: @LeandroAlmeida o background é cor ou imagem?

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente você precisa colocar o *background* de um segundo botão no botão clicado. Tendo isso e usando o `setOnClickListener()` o código abaixo resgata o *background* usando o método `getBackground()` e define o *background* do botão atual usando o método `setBackground()`. Conforme [**a documentação**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)), só é possível usar o `setBackground()` com a versão do Android API level 16+, no entanto observa-se que pode-se usar `setBackgroundDrawable()`, que [**apesar de obsoleto**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)), ainda funciona. Sendo assim, foi inserido uma condição que verifica a versão minima definida no seu projeto. Veja como ficaria:

```
    final ImageButton ib1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib1);
    final ImageButton ib2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib2);

    ib1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Drawable bg = ib1.getBackground();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

                ib2.setBackground(bg);

            } else {
                /* o metodo setBackgroundDrawable está obsoleto,
                porém ainda funciona para que possamos usar*/
                ib2.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
            }
        }
    });
```

**Obs.:** Pode haver outras formas de realizar esse procedimento.

Comment: Eu quero trabalahar a partir da View, e fazendo assim não me está a dar solução.

Comment: Muito obrigado funcionou! :)

Comment: @LeandroAlmeida legal. Que bom que deu tudo certo por ai. Se desta forma funcionou pra você, por favor, valide a resposta. Se precisar de mais alguma coisa, estamos por aqui.

Answer (score 1):

`getDrawable()` retorna um `Drawable` enquanto `setBackgroundResource(int)` tem um `int` como entrada.

Use `findViewById(R.id.imgB6).setBackground(v.getBackground());`

Comment: dá erro no `.setBackground`, "call requires api level 16 (current min 15)"

Comment: `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) findViewById(R.id.imgB6).setBackground(v.getBackground());`

Answer (score 0):

Você está a tentar usar um Drawable como argumento num método que espera um `int`.

Para alterar o background deverá utilizar `setBackground()` e usar `getBackground()` para obter o background do outro botão:

```
findViewById(R.id.imgB6).setBackground(v.getBackground());
```

Como está a usar ImageButton, o código em cima pode não fazer o que pretende.
Vai depender de como as imagens foram atribuídas aos botões.

A principal diferença entre um Button e um ImageButton é este poder ter a ele associada uma imagem que é independente do background. [ImageButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) herda de ImageView.

Se as imagens foram atribuídas, no *xml*, através do atributo `android:src`,  deverá usar `setImageDrawable()` e `getDrawable()`:

```
findViewById(R.id.imgB6).setImageDrawable(v.getDrawable());
```

<sub>Nota: Usar o atributo `android:src` é forma habitual de atribuir a imagem a um ImageButton, se usar `android:Background` é o mesmo que estar a usar um Button.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Faz o Onclick no seu ImagemButton e depois seta a outra imagem do drawable.

`iDdoImagemButton.setBackgroundResource(@drawable/NomeDAIMAGEM);`

**OBS posta o código ou uma imagem

Comment: A coisa é basica de entender... o código é demasiado grande e vc respondeu ao que eu n queria. Eu tenho uma view do ImageButton1 e tenho um ountro ImageButton6

quero por o background do ImageButton1 no ImageButton6

tenho
findViewById(R.id.imgB6) para ter a view do ImageButton6
.setBackgroundResource() para defenir o bacground do ImageButton6

o erro ta em obter o background do ImageButton1
"v.getBackground()"